# What character replacements should be performed to make base 64 encoding URL safe?

Tags: php, perl, url, encoding, base64

In looking at URL safe base 64 encoding, I've found it to be a very non-standard thing.  Despite the copious number of built in functions that PHP has, there isn't one for URL safe base 64 encoding.  On the manual page for [`base64_encode()`](http://us.php.net/base64_encode), most of the comments suggest using that function, wrapped with `strtr()`:

```
function base64_url_encode($input)
{
     return strtr(base64_encode($input), '+/=', '-_,');
}
```

The only Perl module I could find in this area is [MIME::Base64::URLSafe](http://search.cpan.org/~kazuho/MIME-Base64-URLSafe-0.01/lib/MIME/Base64/URLSafe.pm) ([source](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/KAZUHO/MIME-Base64-URLSafe-0.01/lib/MIME/Base64/URLSafe.pm)), which performs the following replacement internally:

```
sub encode ($) {
    my $data = encode_base64($_[0], '');
    $data =~ tr|+/=|\-_|d;
    return $data;
}
```

Unlike the PHP function above, this Perl version drops the '=' (equals) character entirely, rather than replacing it with ',' (comma) as PHP does.  Equals is a padding character, so the Perl module replaces them as needed upon decode, but this difference makes the two implementations incompatible.

Finally, the Python function [urlsafe_b64encode(s)](http://docs.python.org/library/base64.html#base64.urlsafe_b64encode) keeps the '=' padding around, prompting someone to put up [this function](http://snipplr.com/view/15110/urlsafe-base64-functions/) to remove the padding which shows prominently in Google results for ['python base64 url safe'](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=python%20base64%20url%20safe&btnG=Google+Search):

```
from base64 import urlsafe_b64encode, urlsafe_b64decode

def uri_b64encode(s):
    return urlsafe_b64encode(s).strip('=')

def uri_b64decode(s):
    return urlsafe_b64decode(s + '=' * (4 - len(s) % 4))
```

The desire here is to have a string that can be included in a URL without further encoding, hence the ditching or translation of the characters '+', '/', and '='.  Since there isn't a defined standard, **what is the right way?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There does appear to be a standard, it is [RFC 3548](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3548.html), Section 4, *Base 64 Encoding with URL and Filename Safe Alphabet*:

> This encoding is technically identical
>   to the previous one, except for the
>   62:nd and 63:rd alphabet character, as
>   indicated in table 2.

`+` and `/` should be replaced by `- (minus)` and `_ (understrike)` respectively. Any incompatible libraries should be wrapped so they conform to RFC 3548.

Note that this requires that you URL encode the `(pad) =` characters, but I prefer that over URL encoding the `+` and `/` characters from the standard base64 alphabet.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think there is right or wrong. But most popular encoding is

```
'+/=' => '-_.'
```

This is widely used by Google, Yahoo (they call it Y64). The most url-safe version of encoders I  used on Java, Ruby supports this character set.

Comment: +1 for mentioning Y64 and adding some culture to the question

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest running the output of base64_encode through urlencode. For example:

```
function base64_encode_url( $str )
{
    return urlencode( base64_encode( $str ) );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking about the correct way, I'd go with proper URL-encoding as opposed to arbitrary replacement of characters. First base64-encode your data, then further encode special characters like "=" with proper URL-encoding (i.e. `%<code>`).

Comment: I'm down with using the already available functions, but using urlencode() can add a lot of extra length.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try wrapping it in a `urlencode()`? Documentation [here.](http://www.php.net/urlencode)

Comment: That uses an unnecessary number of characters.  Why not just urlencode the binary string in the first place?